# Tactile pull-to-refresh on Chrome on Windows 11 touch device

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-11

I use Chrome 104 on my Windows 11 touch device.

I want to use touch pull-to-refresh on web pages, and after searching on Google it seems it's pretty well known that it's possible to do so just by activating some hidden option under `chrome://flags/` (specifically `chrome://flags/#pull-to-refresh` - see for example [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/pull-to-refresh-google-chrome/#:%7E:text=It%27s%20available%20in%20the%20developer,%2F%23pull%2Dto%2Drefresh.) or [here](https://9to5google.com/2018/02/23/pull-to-refresh-gesture-can-now-be-enabled-on-chrome-for-windows-2-in-1s-and-chromebooks/) or [here](https://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-pull-or-swipe-down-to-refresh-feature-in-google-chrome-on-desktop/) or [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/pull-to-refresh-google-chrome/)).

However, that option doesn't appear in my Chrome flags/experiments pages:
[image]

Plus, if I remember correctly, I use to have this option activated a few months ago though.

How come? What can I do to get back this feature?

Comment: The flag was removed in Stable v100 & Official Beta v101

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is well-known for retiring experimental options that didn't make it
into the stable version. Apparently the option of pull-to-refresh was
simply retired and is now gone forever.

The only way to make it come back is to return to a previous version
of Chrome that supported it, which I don't recommend at all.
You could also post a feature-request in the Chrome Forums.

Or you could try any of the Chrome/Chromium clones which might still
have this option.